# How to resize the facebook iframe application window

Tags: php, html, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a facebook app which run only through a fan page.
Go to app : http://apps.facebook.com/imageassistant/ (You should have a fan page to check this)

**I need to increase the height of my canvas page as much as I can with a fix width value**(If you run my application you will see)

I have a index.php file which include fbmain.php file

```
//index.php
<?php
 include_once "fbmain.php"; // this file do all authentication parts
//some codes
?>
```

I need to resize my all pages in my app
I found some codes related to this from [facebook developer page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.setSize/)

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.Canvas.setSize();
}

// Do things that will sometimes call sizeChangeCallback()

function sizeChangeCallback() {
  FB.Canvas.setSize();
}
```

and this

```
FB.Canvas.setSize({ width: 640, height: 480 }); // Live in the past
```

But I don't know how to use these codes in my app and where should I put those?
Do I have put this code in each and every file in my app?
Do I have to change the app settings in my developer app page also? (IFrame Size to Show scrollbars or Auto-resize before do this)
**Can anyone please post the complete answer including where should I put that?**
Note : I am using php sdk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But I don't know how to use these codes in my app and where should I put those?

There are a number of valid ways of doing this the following is just one:

```
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
    <head>
        <!-- YOUR HEADER CONTENT -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="fb-root"></div>

        <!-- You Page Content HERE -->

        <script>
          window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({appId: 'your app id', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
            FB.Canvas.setSize();
          };
          (function() {
            var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
            e.src = document.location.protocol +
              '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
            document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
          }());
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

> Do I have put this code in each and every file in my app?

If you want the iFrame to resize then you need to include this kind of code in each and every page.

> Do I have to change the app settings in my developer app page also?

For this to work you need to select the auto-resize option in the developer app.

---

You man also want to consider [FB.Canvas.setAutoResize](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.setAutoResize/) if your content's size is dynamic.

You also may come accross issues where FB.Canvas.setSize fires too early in which case you can use setTimeout to delay it - from experience I've found 200ms to be about optimal:

```
          window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({appId: 'your app id', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
            window.setTimeout(
                function() {
                    FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();
                },
                200
            );
          };
```

Comment: Thanks again,it works.
Can you please tell me how to set a fix width for the canvas?(Let say I want a fix width of 500)

Comment: Yes it works.tnx. One more problem. When I scroll down I can see page stuck sometimes since it is loading(When I scroll down I can see page is loading) Can I stop that? I didn't had this problem without re-size code

Comment: Sorry I don't really understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

Just include javascript SDK file in your project.

And then using script tag src attribute include the above file in your index.php file and in index.php write this code :

```
<?php
       echo '<script type="text/javascript"> 
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({appId:'Your AppID here', status: true, cookie: true, 
                        xfbml: true});
            FB.Canvas.setSize({ width: 640, height: 720 });
          };
    </script>';                             
?>
```

This will set your canvas size to specified width and height for all 
    webpages within your App.